# Вывод дочерних ресурсов у дочернего pdoResourse MODX

Tags: modx, pdofield, pdoresourse, pdotools

У меня есть каталог ресурсов:

```html
-Автомобили (7)
--Легковые (8)
---BMW (9)
---AUDI (10)
--Грузовые (11)
---ВАЗ (12)
```

Мне нужно выводить список ресурсов из дочерних ресурсов родителя с ID 7 из легковых и грузовых.
То есть BMW, AUDI, ВАЗ и тд...

У меня получается выводить только весь список, но это не совсем то, что нужно:

```html
[[pdoResources? 
&parents=`7`
&depth=`5`
&tpl=`priceblock`
&sortby=`{"parent":"ASC","menuindex":"ASC"}`
&idx=`1`
&includeTVs=`pricerub,pricename`
]]
```

Есть ли возможность так сделать? Или же нужно разбивать на шаблоны и указывать ID каждого дочернего ресурса вручную ?

Comment: Вы просто хотите не выводить контейнеры? тогда ``&hideContainers=`1` ``

Comment: Без примера того что должно быть на выходе нифига не понятно что ты вообще хочешь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можна задать нужний уровень и parents передаать список радителей тех ресурсов для которых нужно вывести дочерние  код снипетаgetParentsAtLevel:https://forums.modx.com/thread/95675/getresources-listing-resources-of-a-certain-level#dis-post-517925

Answer (score 0):

```
&parents=`[[*id]]`
&resources=`-8,-9,-10,-11,-12`
```

Comment: ну или как написали выше, &hideContainers=`1`. Но в парентс вместо явного id укажите [[*id]]. Если я правильно понял о чем речь, должно работать